# Best XML Based Database

Tags: xml, database, database-design, nosql

I had been assigned to develop a system on where we would get a XML from multiple sources (millions of xml) and put them in some database like and judging from the xml i would receive, there wont be any concrete structure even if they are from the same source. With this reason i think i cannot suggest RDMS and currently looking at NoSQL databases. We need a system that could do CRUD and is fast on Read.

I had been looking at MarkLogic and eXist, which are both XML based NoSQL databases, have anyone had experience with them? and any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I find this topic of discussion constructive, as I am facing a similar issue... maybe it was not constructive to you Code Monkey, that doesn't include the rest of the community. Why censor??

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this project: http://exist.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

You are right in saying that RDBMS would not serve the purpose even if it does support XML datatype these days. I have extensively worked in MarkLogic, and so far it is the best noSQL XMl DB you can have. I have also tried eXist, however it is not much scalable for production usage. MarkLogic gives agility in developement as well with integrated app servers and search engine. Currently it is serving terabytes of XML data in some huge publishing houses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any practical experience with it, but I have read that IBM DB2 has [special XML capabilities](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0311wong/index.html).

SQL Server has an xml field type, but imposes some restrictions when you have such fields in a table. An annoying one (for me), is that you cannot use such a table on a linked server.

Answer (score -1):

Even if the XML doesn't have a particular structure, as long as it's validating XML you could still store it in a traditional SQL database by essentially writing out the DOM. You would have tables for elements and attributes. The elements and attributes would have a foreign key column to a parent element and a column for name.

You say you need to have fast reads. What exactly are you reading? If you'll be looking for specific tags, then a traditional SQL database would still be able to query that pretty quickly.

Comment: There would a xml file of a person with a lot of his/her details, these xml could go up from 12KB - 50KB per xml, i need to search something in the xml itself. I was thinking that putting them into a XML field and doing "select * from table where detail like '%<person information>%' is slow especially if it reach millions of record(this would really be the case after 2-3 months)? Am i right on this one? Thanks

Comment: I think the one or two tags would be separated would be a good idea thanks. On the multiple sources, there is a person XML from multiple companies we fetch data from. These XML might differ from company to company further more on one company it might be different too (from country branch to country branch). Anyhow is what sticking to traditional database is what your suggesting? Thanks a lot